# Matching input letters with a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I'm trying to make a program that will read in words from a .txt file and having the user input letters of own choosing, and the program will give print out all the matches.

This is what I got so far:

```
fil = open("example.txt", "r")
words = fil.readlines()
letters = raw_input("Type in letters: ")
compare = set(letters)

lista = []
for a_line in words:
    a_line = a_line.strip()
    lineword = set(a_line)
    if compare >= lineword:
        lista.append(rad)


print lista
```

Now this works only to a certain degree. It does match the user input with the content of the .txt file, but I want it to be more precise. For example:
If I put in "hrose" it will find me "horse", but it will also find me "roses" with two s, since it only compares elements and not amount

How can I make the program to *only* use the specified letters?

Comment: You're looking for anagrams. Sort the letters in the words, and don't use a set. E.g. horse -> ehors, roses -> eorss.

Comment: I don't think sorting alone will do it. It seems like he's looking for supersets, i.e. "horses" _should_ match "rose".

Comment: Yes, sorry, that part of the source wasn't translated. Edited it now.

@PeterWood And how would I do that? I guess you're suggestion some kind of iteration for every letter against the word?

Comment: If the user letters are `horses` should it match `rose` or `roses`? In other words, do the matches have to be the same length?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def compare(query, word):
    query_count = Counter(query)
    word_count = Counter(word)
    return all([query_count[char] >= word_count[char] for char in word])

>>> compare("hrose", "rose")
True
>>> compare("hrose", "roses")
False
```

Answer (score 1):

[Counters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) are your friend

```
from collections import Counter

fil = open("example.txt", "r")
words = [(a.strip(), Counter(a.strip())) for a in fil.readlines()]

letters = raw_input("Type in letters: ")
letter_count = Counter(letters)

word_list = []
for word, word_count in words:
    if all([letter_count[char] >= word_count[char] for char in word]):
        word_list.append(word)

print word_list
```

looking at the comments, it's possible you may only want exact matches, if so, you don't even need a counter

```
fil = open("example.txt", "r")
words = [(a.strip(), sorted(a.strip())) for a in fil.readlines()]

letters = sorted(raw_input("Type in letters: "))

word_list = [word for word, sorted_word in words if letters == sorted_word]

print word_list
```

Answer (score 0):

you can map a mapping dictionary with key as the letters in the word and value being how many times it occurs in that word.
Now just compare two dictionaries.

```
fil = open("example.txt", "r")
words = fil.readlines()
letters = raw_input("Type in letters: ")
compare = list(letters)
letter_dict = {}
for letter in compare:
    try:
        letter_dict[letter] += 1
    except KeyError:
        letter_dict[letter] = 0

lista = []
for a_line in words:
    a_line = a_line.strip()
    lineword = list(a_line)
    word_dict = {}
    for letter in lineword:
        try:
            word_dict[letter] += 1
        except KeyError:
            word_dict[letter] = 0
    flag = True
    for key, value in letter_dict.items():
        if key not in word_dict or word_dict[key] < value:
           flag = False 
           break;
    if flag:
           lista.append(a_line)  

print lista
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach you could follow is to use set fundtions:

either use `issubset/issuperset`

```
set("horse").issubset(set("hrose")) #returs True
set("horse").issubset(set("roses")) #returns False
```

or

```
set("horse").difference(set("hrose")) #returns empty set based on set length you know close call
set("horse").difference(set("roses")) #returns set(['h'])
```

In the second approach, if you have the choice to choose among multiple options, you could go for result with small length.

Comment: This is what he is already doing, with `>=` instead of `issuperset`, but it doesn't work because of repeated letters.